# how to calculate the total big O value of two algorithms -- is it just O(|f1| + f|2|)?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

say I know the order of magnitude of both algorithms already -- for simplicities sake I will assume O(nLogn) and O(n^2).

is the answer just O(|nLogn| + |n^2|) or can I somehow get it into simpler terms?

I believe if I know the value of n, I could just plug it into the equation, since the total amount of work is the max running time of both.

i know its probably a a stupid question lol.

Comment: "how to calculate the total big O value of two algorithms — is it just O(|f1| + f|2|)?" - what does it mean? do you run both algorithms in serial? parallel? in an unrelated way?

Comment: *I believe if I know the value of n, I could just plug it into the equation* - Big O Notation does not work like that. It only gives an indication of asymptotic behavior, that is, the rate of growth as `n` approaches infinity. In particular, your algorithm may perform significantly worse than the indicated bound for specific (small-ish) `n`s, as long as for all `n`s above a certain size, the bound holds.

Comment: i literally just made up values for the functions, it wasn't an actual function. the example given to study was O(2n^2+2n+1) and O(n^2+9) 

but i was just trying to figure out a general methodology of what i was supposed to do at all

there are no notes to reference, and the book doesn't mention algorithm analysis. I'm assumed to know so i have only a day for a whole crash course in the subject.

My only guess, as shown here came from Wikipedia on getting the sum of two orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 4):

> I know its probably a a stupid question.

Not stupid, but it does indicate that you have not fully grasped what Big O notation means mathematically ... or intuitively.  You should go back to your lecture notes / textbook and reread what they say.

Intuitively, when we say that `f(x)` is `O(g(x))` that means that `f(x)` tends towards being proportional to `g(x)` as `x` gets very big.

So for your example,

- `a(n)` is `O(nlogn)` and `b(n)` is `O(n^2)`
- `a(n) + b(n)` is `O(nlogn + n^2)`

**but**

- `O(nlogn + n^2)` is the same as `O(n^2)`, *because* as `n` gets very large, `nlogn + n^2` tends to being proportional to `n^2`.  (The `nlogn` term gets relatively smaller until eventually it is no longer significant.)

**so**

- `a(n) + b(n)` is `O(nlogn + n^2)` *which is the same as* `O(n^2)`

This can also be proven mathematically, if you are so inclined (or required).

Comment: I didn't get any lecture notes on this subject at all, which is the only reason I came here and asked lol, but thank you. and someone mustve stolen my textbook, I found an outdated edition which said nothing about this (we haven't even used the book) but I'm going to have to buy another in order to see if its in there -- and I have a test coming up before that will be possible

Comment: Surely they teach you to **take lecture notes**.  And if your recommended text book doesn't talk about this, then others do.  And a google search should find you a good / detailed explanation ... intuitive and mathematical.  (And some poor ones too, probably.)

Comment: they do, but at best all I got on this particular subject was the absolute values added together. they really did not go into this, and I think its assumed I already knew it since everyone else did. I have great skills in coding, but ive skipped a ridiculous amount of math and do not have previous math skills.

this cant be that difficult of a problem to do (only things that mess me up are memorizing breaking down quadratics really, its all that keeps me out of calc)

So if i can replace the lecture i never got or find an example i can teach myself how it works.

Comment: *"... but ive skipped a ridiculous amount of math ..."*.  Yea, well that's probably the root cause of your problems.  Not a lot you can do about that in time for your test, but I would recommend that you go back and take some remedial mathematics courses as soon as you can.

Comment: so... another guess here, I'm reading that order of magnitude always gets reduced to the highest order terms... is that why in the above example it reduces to O(n^2), because O(nlogn) is a smaller amount of work than o(n^2)? 

If that's the case this is even simpler than I imagined?

Comment: ok I think I actually see it now, at least a little, and that example is bad because O(logn) is indeed the same as o(n^2).

Not sure if I got it right, but you just add the two values of a(n) and b(n) then reduce any constant coefficient to 1 and use the highest exponential/logarithmic value...

So like a(n) = (2n^2+2n+1)  and b(n) = (n^2+9)

would be something like 3n^2+2n+10, which would reduce to n^2+n+10 which would result in O(n^2) complexity

I might be wrong still, and In that example you really don't have to add them to see it logically, if I followed the right steps

Comment: I meant O(nlogn) is < O(n^2) not is